# how do i call the method in controller class on multiple check box to update the record in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a data table with checkboxes once I select a checkbox I want to update the database and when I select all the checkboxes then all records should be updated with common values like 1;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can do in any client side languages. but, here i used jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each( function(i, field){
    if($("#c"+(i+1)).prop("checked")){
        $("#results").append("you have selected :"+field.name );
    }

    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


  one: <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="c1" value="1" ><br>
  two: <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="c2" value="2"><br>
   three: <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="c3" value="3"><br>
  four: <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="c4" value="4"><br>


<button>click here</button>

<div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

use above way , at the time of client side object creation .